# Uses of hash in shell scripting

Tags: shell-script

What are the uses of the hash character in shell scripting beyond using them in comments or as `$#`; what are other uses?

I want to be able to `grep` the content on each line before hash since there are comments in the same line as code.

The application context is mainly korn shell, the system I use is "HP-UX ***B.11.31 U ia64 *****unlimited-user license".

Comment: You're asking for all of the uses of the hash symbol `#` in bash scripting?

Comment: mainly korn shell

Comment: What are you _actually_ wanting to do? Search through code while ignoring comments?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't find comments simply by using `grep` because of the complexity of the shell's [token recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_03). A `#` that occurs after a backslash, or in a string, or as part of a shell parameter like `$#` or `${parameter#word}`, or (in some shells) numeric constants like base#number, is not treated as a comment.

Comment: OP:yes @roaima that is what I want (also mentioned in question). I have worked on awk and grep. sed awk grep whatever works is fine.

Comment: I would suggest you ask how to search code without comments rather than mixing "uses of hash" with "searching code and comments."

Answer (score 8):

`#` is a special character. A special character is defined as a character that has a meaning beyond its literal meaning. `#` is used for commenting out in a Shell Script.

However there are exceptions, ie such as `#!` is referred to as a "sha-bang". A sha-bang is at the head of a script (the very first lines of code) tells your system that this file is a set of commands to be fed to the command interpreter indicated. Here are some:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #!/bin/bash
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 #!/usr/bin/tcl
 #!/bin/sed -f
 #!/bin/awk -f
```

A command may not follow a comment on the same line. There is no method of terminating the comment, in order for "live code" to begin on the same line. Use a new line for the next command.

Here are some examples:

```
echo "The # here does not begin a comment."
echo 'The # here does not begin a comment.'
echo The \# here does not begin a comment.
echo The # here begins a comment.

echo ${PATH#*:}       # Parameter substitution, not a comment.
echo $(( 2#101011 ))  # Base conversion, not a comment.
```

You can alternatively google specific uses of `#` that you're unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of hash (`#`) uses in Kornshell beyond their use as a start of comments; `$#`, `${#}`, `${var#pat}`, `${var##pat}`, `${#var}`, `${#arr[*]}`, `${#arr[@]}`, `base#number` (i.e. literal numbers), and it can be part of patterns, e.g. `[#]`, or literally in strings `"...#..."`, or as part of the text data in "here-docs".

Newer versions of ksh will also support `$( n <# )`, `${var/#pat/str}`, `<<#`, `<# ((expr))`, `># ((expr))`, `<#/pat`, `<##/pat`, and `#` has a specific meaning in ksh's builtin `printf` format specifiers.

(I may still have missed one or two applications.)

References:

ksh93: `http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html`

ksh88: `http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html`